# Não consigo logar no Heroku

Tags: heroku

Eu instalei o Toolbelt no windows 7 e quando fui logar deu essa mensagem;

```
wlady@wlady-PC MINGW32 ~/workspace/backup/wladimir (master)
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: tecnico100@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
 !    Login is currently incompatible with git bash/cygwin
 !    In the meantime, login via cmd.exe
 !    https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84

wlady@wlady-PC MINGW32 ~/workspace/backup/wladimir (master)
```

eu já pesquisei se era variavel de ambiente para configurar, mas eu não acho que é isso, alguém tem uma sugestão?

meu email de login é esse mesmo.

Comment: a mensagem de erro é: no momento é incompatível se logar via cygwin use o cmd. Você tentou usar o cmd?

Comment: eu tentei, ele não reconhece como comando valido.